# UI file showing different in desktop and laptop

Tags: qt, qt4

In my project one ui file is there , when i am viewing that ui file in my laptop( having 15 inch screen ) half of the ui file is not showing , when i am running the same project in my desktop(having bigger screen than my laptop) the same ui file is showing completely . What might be  the reason and how to show the full ui in my laptop?

Comment: What is the resolution of your laptop and desktop?  The screen size doesn't matter directly.

Comment: Desktop Resolution - 1440 * 900
Laptop Resolution - 1366 * 768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution , i just decrease the heigt of my UI file . Now its working fine both in my desktop as well as in my laptop ..